# Amazon instance root directory /var/www/html not working

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, linux-kernel

unfortunately, I did one mistake by directory permission to

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/www/html
```

so, my website is not working. this is a problem, so how to solve this?
anyone please help me. i didn't know the amazon default directory permission in /var/www/html and /var/www/

Comment: Could always boot a new ubuntu image to check what the default is.

Comment: Please try and explain what the issue actually is. Your question doesn't provide any information to help us answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Default permissions for default Apache document root could be restored by:

```
chmod 755 /var/www
chmod 755 /var/www/html
```

Comment: Those are the default permissions on Amazon Linux, CentOS and RedHat. If those "are not working" you have a problem somewhere else.